# Split DOCX file by pages

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, xmldocument

What is the **best way to split DOCX document by pages** using C# (as a result I need to have N files, where N - amount of pages)? I can't have dependencies from Microsoft.Interop.Word because of client restrictions.

P.S. I know that Word XML structure doesn't have info about paging. However MS Word automation can easy split document by pages somehow.